# Parse JSON array with Swiftyjson in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swifty-json

I'm working with Swiftyjson in Swift 2.3. I've been able to parse json arrays into a UITableview with no problem until I got the following json response:

```
{
  "CAR": [
    {
      "SID": "1",
      "NAME": "BMW",
    },
    {
      "SID": "2",
      "NAME": "MERCEDES",
    },
],
  "BIKE": [
    {
      "SID": "3",
      "NAME": "KAWASAKI",
    },
    {
      "SID": "4",
      "NAME": "HONDA",
    },
 ]
}
```

**QUESTION** How do I parse "CAR" and "BIKE" into tableview sections and have their items under each section? I've managed to get the "keys" using:

```
// Other Code 
let json = JSON(data)
for (key, subJson) in json {
    self.array.append(key)
}

print(self.array)
["CAR", "BIKE"]
```

I wanted to know how to loop through each section and get their items properly. Any help would be great!

Comment: Show the tableView method that you are trying currently

Comment: That's a very very frequently asked question: Here are many related questions and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswifty-json%5D+parse+json

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown where you are getting your json data from, I have tested this by having your JSON above in a .json file. Also this doesn't use SwiftyJSON but you will be able to modify the syntax to get the same result.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tableData = Dictionary<String,Array<Dictionary<String,String>>>()

    var sections = Array<String>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        load(file: "document")
    }

    func load(file:String) {

        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "json") else { return }

        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) else { return }

        guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) else { return }

        guard let dict = json as? Dictionary<String,Array<Dictionary<String,String>>> else { return }

        self.tableData = dict

        self.sections = dict.keys.sorted()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return self.sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        let key = self.section[section]

        return key
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let key = self.section[indexPath.section]

        return self.tableData[key]?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        let key = self.section[indexPath.section]

        let cellData = self.tableData[key]?[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = cellData?["NAME"]

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "SID: \(cellData?["SID"] ?? "Unknown")"

        return cell
    }
}
```

This is how it looks on an iPhone.

[image]

Comment: You're right about the JSON options @vadian. With regards to the table data, since there was little data I did it this way just to give an idea of how to do the table view. I have modified the code to have a separate array to store the sections so that tableData.keys is not being called all the time.